# Android listview customAdapter change row gravity & color

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater, custom-adapter

I have the following CustomAdapter for my `ListView`:

```
public class CustomConvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Conv> convItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomConvAdapter(Activity activity, List<Conv> convItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.convItems = convItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return convItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return convItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Conv m = convItems.get(position);

    if ((convertView == null)) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conv_row, null);
    }

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.body);


    // thumbnail image
    //thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    name.setText(c.getName());

    body.setText(c.getBody());

    return convertView;
}
```

I would change my `R.layout.conv_row` properties (gravity, background, textcolor) like a bubblechat: if the message is mine (name== String myname) then right gravity and bgcolor = #color1, else gravity left and bgcolor = #color2.
Saw many example about that but I would implement it using my CustomAdapter.
Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Edit my code as:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now I get

> com.xxxxx.yyyy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1179)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1261)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)

etc,etc

How could I fix it?

Comment: in function getview() you already have your elements , just need to inflate the layout too to change the gravity

Comment: and you dont know how to set Gravity ?

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramas = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
view.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: that's for relative layout :)

Comment: @ПетърПетров I've converted it in LinearLayout but in both case (Relative and Linear) it asks me for arguments in `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams();`
Quoting Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: @ПетърПетров posted my edit following your suggestion but got an exception

Comment: Layout params must be in type of your main layout. if it's RelativeLayout, then in code must be RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(); otherwise for linear

Comment: show me your xml item layout

Comment: @ПетърПетров I've post it in another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set set gravity of your parentView. Let suppose that parentView contsains text and body. Then you can do something like this.

```
if (isMe) {
            holder.parentView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            holder.parentView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@ПетърПетров this is it:

```
conv_row.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:textColor="#ffaaaaaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you.